# How can I obtain some of all possible combinations in R?

Tags: r, nonparametric, combinatorics

Sometimes I want to do an exact test by examining all possible combinations of the data to build an empirical distribution against which I can test my observed differences between means.  To find the possible combinations I'd typically use the combn function.  The choose function can show me how many possible combinations there are.  It is very easy for the number of combinations to get so large that it is not possible to store the result of the combn function, e.g. combn(28,14) requires a 2.1 Gb vector.  So I tried writing an object that steped through the same logic as the combn function in order to provide the values off an imaginary "stack" one at a time.  However, this method (as I instantiated it) is easily 50 times slower than combn at reasonable combination sizes, leading me to think it will also be painfully slow for larger combination sizes.

Is there a better algorithm for doing this sort of thing than the algorithm used in combn?Specifically is there a way to generate and pull the Nth possible combination without calculating through all previous combinations?

Comment: Has anyone noticed that the number of questions that should be in StackOverflow R rocketed up here recently?

Comment: Why not making random sampling?

Comment: @John: If you feel that way discuss the issue at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-to-speed-up-questions, no need to be snarky.

Comment: @mbq:  Random sampling will quickly provide a reasonable approximate, especially with well behaved data.  However, I did specify that my goal was an exact test.

Comment: @drknexus That's why it was a comment not an answer.

Comment: I'm sure you have some reason for doing this in R, but wouldn't a low-level language like C be more appropriate if you are looking for speed? It would be nastier to code, but would run faster, no doubt.

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, it probably would be faster in C but since the outputs are being used in R it seems clearer from a reproducible research standpoint to use only R code.  Moreover, (the real answer) I'm more comfortable in R than C and haven't learned how to call C code from R yet.

Comment: You're trying to do a permutation test, but there are too many combinations for a census, so understandably you'd like to sample them - this much is typical. However, most commonly in this situation they are sampled *with replacement* rather than without, which is typically much easier to do. Unless you're sampling an appreciable fraction of the combinations the slight increase in variance will be worth the saving in time and effort.

Comment: @Glen_b Certainly.  I was hoping there was a magic bullet to reduce the time and effort to sample without replacement, but I think the answers to this question show that there is no such bullet.

Comment: There's some neat algorithms for "numbering" the combinations and sampling them (which in many situations are reeasonably rapid), but once the numbers grow large it's actually nearly impossible to choose between all the combinations with equal probability, because the number of combinations grow so large the pseudorandom number generators people tend to use don't generate enough values to assign them all effectively equal probability -- indeed often they have available orders of magnitude fewer values than there are combinations, so some combinations (often most of them) can't show up at all.

Comment: There are ways to mitigate this issue somewhat (which will solve the problem for one case or another), but by choosing larger cases again, this combinatorial explosion catches you up quickly. By contrast, sampling with replacement usually avoids problems associated with the explosive growth in the number of combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to trade processing speed for memory (which I think you do), I would suggest the following algorithm:

- Set up a loop from 1 to N Choose K, indexed by i
- Each i can be considered an index to a [combinadic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289166%28VS.71%29.aspx), decode as such
- Use the combination to perform your test statistic, store the result, discard the combination
- Repeat

This will give you all N Choose K possible combinations without having to create them explicitly. I have code to do this in R if you'd like it (you can email me at mark dot m period fredrickson at-symbol gmail dot com).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it solves (what I think) is the harder of the problems I was looking for a solution to - picking a particular combination out without calculating the preceding values.  Unfortunately, it is still very slow.  Perhaps as mentioned here and elsewhere a binary search would help speed things up.  Perhaps the best approach is to have one thread generating the combinations stepwise as in mbq's answer and another thread reading them off and testing them.

Answer (score 1):

Generating combinations is pretty easy, see for instance [this](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/generating-combinations-1/); write this code in R and then process each combination at a time it appears.

Comment: But will this cope with very large combinations?

Comment: @csgillespie Well, I believe so -- it works *in situ*,  so only one combination is stored in memory at a time, and the results of simulation can be also aggregated to eliminate the need of storing them. This will of course work terribly long, but exhaustive searches usually do. For speed it could be written in C, but then along with the simulation part, which probably is way slower than a generator step.

Comment: That looks almost identical to how R's combn function is already doing things.  I wrote up a version of combn that does take combinations off the stack one at a time, and as mbq says because it is only storing one combination in memory at a time it can handle very large combinations.  The problem with doing it in R is that doing a step-by-step approach in a function typically involves reading the state variables into the function, manipulating them, then storing them back out to global - which seems to just slow everything /way/ down.